# Odoo ParseError: "Invalid view definition Error detail : Model not found

Tags: python, postgresql, xml-parsing, odoo-9

Please since yesterday I'm trying to install a module on Odoo 9 but I got this error:

```
Odoo ParseError: "Invalid view definition 
Error detail : 
Model not found: employee.register

Context of error :
View `employee.form`
[view_id: 547, xml_id: n/a, model: employee.register, parent_id: n/a]
None" while parsing /opt/odoo/addons/lci_gestpaie_tic/views/employee.xml:7, near
```

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="employee_form">
    <field name="name">employee.form</field>  
    <field name="model">employee.register</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Employee">

            <label string="Nom"/>
            <field name="nom"/>

            <label string="Prenom"/>
            <field name="prenom"/>

            <label string="Date de Naissance"/>
            <field name="date_naissance"/>

            <label string="Lieu de naissance"/>
            <field name="lieu_naissance"/>

            <label string="CNI"/>
            <field name="cni"/>

            <label string="Salaire de Base"/>
            <field name="salaire_base"/>

            <label string="Date embauche"/>
            <field name="date_embauche"/>

            <label string="Sexe"/>
            <field name="sexe"/>

            <label string="Situation matrimoniale"/>
            <field name="situation_matrimoniale"/>

            <label string="Nombre enfants"/>
            <field name="nombre_enfant"/>

            <label string="Telephone"/>
            <field name="telephone"/>

            <label string="Email"/>
            <field name="email"/>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

## Here's the structure of my modules and my source code

```
my_module
    |models
        | __init__.py
        | emlpoyee.py
    |views
        | employee.xml
    __init__.py
    __openerp__.py
```

## my_modules.**init**.py

```
import models
```

## ../models.**init**.py

```
import employee
```

## ../models.**openerp**.py

```
{
    'name': 'LCI',
    'version': '0.1',
    'category': 'LCI',
    'summary': """
        Summary of the module
    """,
    'author': 'LCI Sarl',
    'website': 'http://lcicm.com',
    'depends': ['base'],
    'data': ['views/employee.xml'],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
}
```

## ../views.employee.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<openerp>
<data>

    <!--formulaire enregistrement-->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="employee_form">
        <field name="name">employee.form</field>  
        <field name="model">employee.register</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Employee">

                <label string="Nom"/>
                <field name="nom"/>

                <label string="Prenom"/>
                <field name="prenom"/>

                <label string="Date de Naissance"/>
                <field name="date_naissance"/>

                <label string="Lieu de naissance"/>
                <field name="lieu_naissance"/>

                <label string="CNI"/>
                <field name="cni"/>

                <label string="Salaire de Base"/>
                <field name="salaire_base"/>

                <label string="Date embauche"/>
                <field name="date_embauche"/>

                <label string="Sexe"/>
                <field name="sexe"/>

                <label string="Situation matrimoniale"/>
                <field name="situation_matrimoniale"/>

                <label string="Nombre enfants"/>
                <field name="nombre_enfant"/>

                <label string="Telephone"/>
                <field name="telephone"/>

                <label string="Email"/>
                <field name="email"/>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <!--affichage de la liste des employes-->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="employee_tree">
        <field name="name">employee.tree</field>
        <field name="model">employee.register</field>
        <field name="type">tree</field>

        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Employee List">

                <field name="nom"/>
                <field name="prenom"/>
                <field name="date_naissance"/>
                <field name="lieu_naissance"/>
                <field name="cni"/>                  
                <field name="salaire_base"/>
                <field name="date_embauche"/>
                <field name="sexe"/>
                <field name="situation_matrimoniale"/>
                <field name="nombre_enfant"/>
                <field name="telephone"/>
                <field name="email"/>

            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <!--actions qui seront executees-->
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_employee">
        <field name="name">Employee</field>
        <field name="res_model">employee.register</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

    <!--nos differents menus-->
    <menuitem name="GestPaie" id="lci_gestpaie_tic"/>
    <menuitem name="Employee" id="employee_gestpaie_section" parent="lci_gestpaie_tic"/>
    <menuitem name="Create Employee" id="employee_register" parent="employee_gestpaie_section" action="action_employee"/>

</data>
</openerp>
```

## ../models/employee.py

```
from openerp import fields, models

class EmployeeRegister(models.Model):
    _name = 'employee.register'

    # attributs de Employee
    nom = fields.Char(required=True)
    prenom = fields.Char(required=True)
    date_naissance = fields.Date(required=True)
    lieu_naissance = fields.Char(required=True)
    cni = fields.Char(required=True)
    salaire_base = fields.Integer(required=True)
    date_embauche = fields.Date(required=True)
    sexe = fields.Char(required=True) # M pour Masculin, F pour Feminin
    situation_matrimoniale = fields.String()
    nbre_enfant = fields.Integer()
    telephone = fields.Char(required=True)
    email = fields.Char(required=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `my_module/models/__init__.py` should be a line that imports `employee`:

```
import employee
```

Comment: Sorry it's a mistake my_modules/models/__init__.py import emplyee! I've corrected it!

Answer (score 1):

i've resolved the problem it was a cache problem so i did

```
./openerp_server stop
```

then

```
./openerp_server stop
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this and it will work okay.

In my_module/models/**init**.py should be a line that imports employee:

```
from . import employee
```